# No me funciona el boton agregado desde DOM

Tags: javascript, funciones, dom, eventos

Tengo una función que agrega datos desde un array de objetos. Crea en el DOM los elementos que necesito. Pero cuando quiero probar los botones para agregarle eventos, no me sirven

```
function createCoin(index){
    const createStruct = document.createElement('div')
    // createStruct.style = 'display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); grid-template-rows: 1fr; justify-items: start; align-items: center;margin: 1rem 0'
    createStruct.className = 'coin__main__container'

    createStruct.innerHTML = 
        `</div class="coin__main__container">
            <div class="coin__logo"><img src="${coins[index].imgUrl}"></div>
            <div class="coin__moneda">${coins[index].name}</div>
            <div class="coin__abreviatura">${coins[index].id}</div>
            <div class="coin__price">${coins[index].price}</div>
            <div class="coin__add"><button id="btn__add__portfolio">Agregar</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="coin__separator"></div><div class="coin__separator"></div><div class="coin__separator"></div><div class="coin__separator"></div><div class="coin__separator"></div>
        `;

    main__section = document.getElementById('cotizaciones__container').appendChild(createStruct)
}

addBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('Works')
})
```

Mi pregunta es: Como puedo hacer para que al agregar los elementos me tome como valido el uso del botón?

https://crypther.vercel.app/ <- Esa es la página si no me explico bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dos consejos y algunas otra correcciones, junto a la solución.

### Las IDs tienen que ser únicas

Ten cuidado cuando generes elementos, como en este caso buttons si les das la misma id. No es válido que en un mismo documento HTML existan elementos con id repetidas. Usa una clase como bien te sugiere el tocayo AL3XANDER y querySelector all. Para iterar entonces podrías usar forEach mismo:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".btn__add__portfolio").forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        alert('works')
    }
})
```

### A veces conviene crear los elementos en lugar de usar innerHTML

En este caso, si usas document.createElement("button") para crear un botón te ahorras queries fuera del contexto de creación y puedes darle el comportamiento directamente al botón, y no solo eso, también acceder a variables durante el contexto del botón más fácilmente.

Si quieres seguir usando innerHTML para la mayor parte del cuerpo de la función podrías hacer algo como

```js
    createStruct.innerHTML = `<div class="coin__main__container">
            <div class="coin__logo"><img src="${coins[index].imgUrl}"></div>
            <div class="coin__moneda">${coins[index].name}</div>
            <div class="coin__abreviatura">${coins[index].id}</div>
            <div class="coin__price">${coins[index].price}</div>
            <div class="coin__add"></div>
        </div>`;

     // Creas el botón
     const addButton = document.createElement('button')
     // Lo añades al div donde lo añadías antes.
     createStruct.querySelector('.coin__add').appendChild(addButton)
     // Le añades el listener
     addButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
         alert("Funciona. Coin seleccionada: " + coins[index].name)
     })
...
```

Nota 2 cosas:

1. El querySelector lo haces sobre createStruct por tanto seleccionará el único elemento con clase coin__add que tiene, que por cierto ha quedado vacío en el innerHTML para este fin.
2. Estamos definiendo el comportamiento del botón DENTRO del método, por tanto tenemos acceso directo a las variables en ese momento y podemos aprovechar lo que en programación se entiende como clausura o closure, que en burdo resumen significa que los elementos retienen o recuerden el contexto en el que fueron creado.

#### Erratas y consejos menores

1. Tienes un div que está comenzando con una etiqueta de cierre `</div>` en lugar de `<div>`
2. No uses elementos con fines de estilo. En su lugar, considera dar márgenes vía css a los elementos pertinentes.
3. Considera usar una sintaxis semántica (por ejemplo, en lugar de ese div podrías usar `<article>` que es válido para entradas, artículos de una tienda, items de una colección, etc, mientras tengan un concepto de contenido y representación de una entidad del sistema.

Comment: Me ayudaste de una forma que no te haces una idea. Aparte de tomarte el tiempo para explicarme. Muchisimas gracias :D

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:
En el botón cambia el ID por class
Por qué si llamas solo por el ID te traerá solo el primer elemento que encuentre.
Con class puedes hacer lo siguiente
`Let addBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn__add__portfolio")`

Entonces ahora podrás ejecutar tu addEventListener con cada elemento.